# Arabic labels do not display correctly in Geoserver

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, geoserver, qgis, gml-geographic-markup-lan

I have geoserver installed with Tomcat and the text labeling do not display correctly . where can i set the Arabic encoding in geosever?
the labeling appear well in QGIS but when i publish it in geoserver i get this problem .

[image: [labeling in geoserver]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPghC.jpg)

[image: labeling in QGIS]

[The shape file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1f98y4tuaUnIi9-LysQbmuBtZ2cB6C8UF)
 Here Is the SLD :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sld:StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" version="1.0.0">
    <sld:UserLayer>
        <sld:LayerFeatureConstraints>
            <sld:FeatureTypeConstraint/>
        </sld:LayerFeatureConstraints>
        <sld:UserStyle>
            <sld:Name>sea</sld:Name>
            <sld:Title/>
            <sld:IsDefault>1</sld:IsDefault>
            <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
                <sld:Name>group 0</sld:Name>
                <sld:FeatureTypeName>Feature</sld:FeatureTypeName>
                <sld:SemanticTypeIdentifier>generic:geometry</sld:SemanticTypeIdentifier>
                <sld:SemanticTypeIdentifier>simple</sld:SemanticTypeIdentifier>
                <sld:Rule>
                    <sld:Name>default rule</sld:Name>
                    <sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
                        <sld:Fill>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#1B9E77</sld:CssParameter>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.5</sld:CssParameter>
                        </sld:Fill>
                        <sld:Stroke>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="stroke">#1B9E77</sld:CssParameter>
                        </sld:Stroke>
                    </sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
                    <sld:TextSymbolizer>
                        <sld:Label>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>ARABIC</ogc:PropertyName>
                        </sld:Label>
                        <sld:Font>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</sld:CssParameter>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="font-size">12.0</sld:CssParameter>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="font-style">normal</sld:CssParameter>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="font-weight">bold</sld:CssParameter>
                        </sld:Font>
                        <sld:LabelPlacement>
                            <sld:PointPlacement>
                                <sld:AnchorPoint>
                                    <sld:AnchorPointX>0.5</sld:AnchorPointX>
                                    <sld:AnchorPointY>0.5</sld:AnchorPointY>
                                </sld:AnchorPoint>
                            </sld:PointPlacement>
                        </sld:LabelPlacement>
                        <sld:Fill>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#000000</sld:CssParameter>
                        </sld:Fill>
                        <sld:VendorOption name="spaceAround">2</sld:VendorOption>
                    </sld:TextSymbolizer>
                </sld:Rule>
            </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
        </sld:UserStyle>
    </sld:UserLayer>
</sld:StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Comment: please add the relevant part of the SLD and the QML files to the question. The most likely issue is a missing font on the GeoServer machine.

Comment: please edit the question

Comment: @Ian Turton . i have edited the question with the SLD

Comment: Does arial have Arabic characters?

Comment: Yes .. its the same font used in QGIS and it shows Arabic well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common problem is that you have miss set the character encoding, check the store page:

[image]

With my test data I get this with a setting of "windows-1250"

[image]

Switching to the (in my case) correct "UTF-8" gives this, which is better.

[image]

And finally using a "better" font than Arial (Trocchi) fills out the Chinese as well as the Arabic characters.

[image]

**Update**

So experimenting with your shapefile and SLD and googling "windows arabic character set" led me to setting the Shapefile datastore DBF character set to "Windows-1256" which seems to work.

[image]

Comment: can you provide a link to your shapefile?

Comment: Here is the link to the shapefile used   https://drive.google.com/open?id=1f98y4tuaUnIi9-LysQbmuBtZ2cB6C8UF

Comment: Thank you @ Ian Turton .. i used these settings and it worked very well