# Issue on Geoserver Label

Tags: geoserver

I use geoserver 2.16.2, I used textsymbolizer to labeling features on the map.In the geoserver the polygons showed correctly but the text-s are displayed as some special characters/ symbols in label and legend text.
how to get correct text as a label and legend description.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9B7GT.png)

Comment: if you can give an example of how you used textsymbolizer, other users will have a better understanding of your situation and how your problem can be resolved

Comment: <TextSymbolizer>
            <Label>
              <ogc:PropertyName>name</ogc:PropertyName>
            </Label>
            <Font />
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
          </TextSymbolizer>

--- but the label is displayed as some non-readable symbols.....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Arabic labels do not display correctly in Geoserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56323836/arabic-labels-do-not-display-correctly-in-geoserver)